Why'd rational investors never cut losses and re-invest into same strike, unless they knew something?
How can I re-write Why'd rational investors never cut losses and re-invest into same strike, unless they knew something? to make it on topic? 

The question is unsalvageable.
You are giving a quote which is opinion based, (and in my opinion complete nonsense), and then asking another's opinion to interpret it.
No one will on this site will respond to that.
